# org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.0.0-rc01'] was not found

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-7.0

After updating my Adnroid Studio to Android Studio 2021.1.1 RC 1 and wanted to increase the Android Gralde plugin from `7.1.0-beta05` to `7.0.0-rc01` . Unfortunately I get

> Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.0.0-rc01'] was not
> found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Try:
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.0.0-rc01'] was not found
>   in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.0.0-rc01')
>   Searched in the following repositories:
>   Google
>   MavenRepo
>   Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, after doing a lpt of research I decided to downgrade as the problem is with gradle you can [follow this link to downgrade.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422057/new-android-project-with-gradle-7-1-0-alpha03-and-composer-doesnt-build)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).